# SpEL: logging-channel-adapter expression throwing exception for escape character \n

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I want to print header and payload on console on new line by removing braces from headers, getting error for below configuration:

```
    <logging-channel-adapter id="logger" channel="auditChannel" level="INFO" expression="'Headers: '+ \n headers.replaceFirst('{','').replaceFirst('}','') +'Payload:'+ \n payload"/>
```

e.g.-

```
    Headers:
    timestamp=1429088482916, id=640b5c94-ea8d-4d9d-8a50-7dc8f201be47..
    Payload:
    Actual message
```

Generally if I print header through logging channel adaper it gives output like:

```
{timestamp=1429088482916, id=640b5c94-ea8d-4d9d-8a50-7dc8f201be47...}
```

I need output as above in the example.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Hi Gary, Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the XML DOM parser converts `'\n'` to `"\\n"`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668655/how-to-put-new-line-in-spring-epression-language/29669284#29669284) for a work-around.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was tring by using **#{systemProperties['line.seperator']}**

Comment: That won't work because `#{...}` is resolved once during initialization (to `\n`) so it's the same as including it as a literal. The `T(...)...` is invoked each time.