# How to put “new line” in Spring Expression Language?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

What would be the exact SpEL expression to go to the new line. Here is my configuration:

```
 <logging-channel-adapter id="log"
    channel="loggingChannel" level="INFO" 
    expression="'DealId: '+ payload.dealId \n + 'Name: '+ payload.name" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this as a work-around:

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" logger-name="tapInbound"
    expression="'DealId: '+ payload.dealId + T(System).getProperty('line.separator') + 'Name: '+ payload.name"
    level="INFO" />
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, SpEL supports escape characters, the problem is the java DOM parser doesn't understand escapes.

This works too...

```
expression="'DealId: '+ payload.dealId + '&#10;Name: '+ payload.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expression="'DealId: '+ payload.dealId'+  T(System).lineSeparator()+.......'"
```